# porting python class to Julialang

Tags: julia

I am seeing that Julia explicitly does NOT do classes... and I should instead embrace mutable structs..  am I going down the correct path here??  I diffed my trivial example against an official flux library but cannot gather how do I reference `self` like a python object.. is the cleanest way to simply pass the type as a parameter in the function??

**Python**

```
# Dense Layer
class Layer_Dense
    
    def __init__(self, n_inputs, n_neurons):
        self.weights = 0.01 * np.random.randn(n_inputs, n_neurons)
        self.biases = np.zeros((1, n_neurons))

    def forward(self, inputs):
        pass
```

My **JuliaLang** version so far

```
mutable struct LayerDense
    num_inputs::Int64
    num_neurons::Int64
    weights
    biases
end


function forward(layer::LayerDense, inputs)
    layer.weights = 0.01 * randn(layer.num_inputs, layer.num_neurons)
    layer.biases = zeros((1, layer.num_neurons))
end
```

The flux libraries version of a dense layer... which looks very different to me.. and I do not know what they're doing or why.. like where is the `forward` pass call, is it here in flux just named after the layer `Dense`???

source : https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/blob/b78a27b01c9629099adb059a98657b995760b617/src/layers/basic.jl#L71-L111

```
struct Dense{F, M<:AbstractMatrix, B}
  weight::M
  bias::B
  σ::F
  function Dense(W::M, bias = true, σ::F = identity) where {M<:AbstractMatrix, F}
    b = create_bias(W, bias, size(W,1))
    new{F,M,typeof(b)}(W, b, σ)
  end
end

function Dense(in::Integer, out::Integer, σ = identity;
               initW = nothing, initb = nothing,
               init = glorot_uniform, bias=true)

  W = if initW !== nothing
    Base.depwarn("keyword initW is deprecated, please use init (which similarly accepts a funtion like randn)", :Dense)
    initW(out, in)
  else
    init(out, in)
  end

  b = if bias === true && initb !== nothing
    Base.depwarn("keyword initb is deprecated, please simply supply the bias vector, bias=initb(out)", :Dense)
    initb(out)
  else
    bias
  end

  return Dense(W, b, σ)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an equivalent of your Python code in Julia:

```
mutable struct Layer_Dense
    weights::Matrix{Float64}
    biases::Matrix{Float64}

    Layer_Dense(n_inputs::Integer, n_neurons::Integer) =
        new(0.01 * randn(n_inputs, n_neurons),
            zeros((1, n_neurons)))
end

forward(ld::Layer_Dense, inputs) = nothing
```

What is important here:

- here I create an [inner constructor](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/#man-inner-constructor-methods) only, as [outer constructor](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/#man-outer-constructor-methods) is not needed; as opposed in the Flux.jl code you have linked the `Dense` type defines both inner and outer constructors
- in python `forward` function does not do anything, so I copied it in Julia (your Julia code worked a bit differently); note that instead of `self` one should pass an instance of the object to the function as the first argument (and add `::Layer_Dense` type signature so that Julia knows how to correctly dispatch it)
- similarly in Python you store only `weights` and `biases` in the class, I have reflected this in the Julia code; note, however, that for performance reasons it is better to provide an explicit type of these two fields of `Layer_Dense` struct

> like where is the `forward` pass call

In the code you have shared only constructors of `Dense` object are defined. However, in the lines below [here](https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/blob/b78a27b01c9629099adb059a98657b995760b617/src/layers/basic.jl#L143) and [here](https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/blob/b78a27b01c9629099adb059a98657b995760b617/src/layers/basic.jl#L145) the `Dense` type is defined to be a functor.
Functors are explained [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/#Function-like-objects) (in general) and in [here](https://github.com/FluxML/Functors.jl) (more specifically for your use case)

Comment: thanks! I just will modify the answer on my side a bit by saving the `num_neurons` and `num_inputs` to variables.. but this should do it.. The constructor was what I really was not seeing anywhere clearly.  thank you!

Comment: regarding `forward` doing nothing, yes I am following along a book that uses python to write neural networks from scratch... but using JuliaLang instead as a challenge to myself and to hopefully help grow my understanding of Julialang

Comment: Note that if you care about performance, you don't want to use `Matrix{Float64}`. `Matrix{Float32}` will be about 2x faster on CPU, and 32x faster on GPU.

Comment: @Oscar Smith is right. I wanted to save the complexity of parametric types in the answer, and in the question `Float64` values were generated, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Parametric-Types for tips how to define the struct in a general way.